# How will aiport operations at KOAK be affected when taxiway W is promoted to a runway?

Tags: runways, taxiing, airport-design

For the record, my question is not about [*mistakenly* using a taxiway as a runway](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24023).

I've noticed recent changes to the sectional and [TAC VFR](https://skyvector.com/?ll=37.72412411070363,-122.23217980340931&chart=127&zoom=1) maps around [Metropolitan Oakland International Airport](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KOAK) (OAK/KOAK) - it appears that Taxiway W is being "promoted" to a runway close to, and parallel to, Runway 12/30.

Based on the [airport map](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1802/pdf/00294AD.PDF) (PDF) and confirmed by the Google Earth image below, aircraft departing and landing on 12/30 (presumably soon-to-be 12R/30L) will have to taxi up or down this new runway.  From the looks of it, this runway will just be marginally long enough (about 7200 ft / 2195 m) to handle short-range commercial operations; certainly the longer runway will still need to be used.

This then begs the question:  How would airport operations be affected if both runways were active?

[image]
From Google Earth and Skyvector.com

Comment: Your link to the airport diagram was via IP Address (155.178.201.160), which is risky, because we have no idea what site we're visiting (even though it is likely an FAA site).  I changed your link to the well known SkyVector site.

Comment: This happened in September 2017, and was only temporary while they closed the main runway for repaving. They did the same thing in 2001. The problem is OAK only has one runway long enough for widebodies/international flights, so shutting it down isn't an option.

Comment: @user71659 that sounds like an answer.

Comment: @abelenky: I only linked what the airnav.com site had, but thank you for fixing this.

Comment: @PeterGreen I was expecting the answer to be something like the runways are too close for simultaneous operations, and FAA standards require Part 139 runways to have parallel taxiways.

Comment: @abelenky Please tell [the FAA](https://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=155.178.201.160?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&showNonArinTopLevelNet=false&ext=netref2) that that's risky. They've been doing it for many years and show no sign of stopping.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Oakland airport runway 12/30 is undergoing a "Rehabilitation" and during the rehabilitation taxiway Whiskey (W) will be serving as an alternate runway.

Therefore, your question "How would airport operations be affected if both runways were active" won't be an issue.   Please see the notice below.

[image]

Comment: Just curious, what is the date of this notice?  I couldn't find it on www.oaklandairport.com.

Comment: @p1268 - the date on the bottom of the page (it's two pages) shows it was "announced" on May 31, 2017. http://www.oaklandairport.com/wp-content/uploads/OAK-Runway-12-30-Rehabilitation-Fact-Sheet-2017-r12_-PostCon.pdf

Comment: This plan sounds like it could lead to pilots lining up wrong for landing and (at best) having to go around when they see the construction equipment in their way.  How would the airport mitigate this possibility?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - this should not really be a problem if the pilot reads the appropriate NOTAM and reviews the airport diagram prior to arrival.  Also, ATC would typical be extra vigilant to ensure that aircraft landing on (alternate 12/30) are lined up correctly.

Comment: Presumably they will also place one of those big flashing X's that are used during any other sort of runway maintenance at either end of the closed runway.